# Best way to get required row

Tags: mysql

I would like to write a query that checks the particular record and if it is not found it should return the other result

For example:

```
SNO | FIRST_COLUMN | SECOND_COLUMN | STATUS
1   | value1       | value2        | 1
2   | value1       | value2        | 1
3   | value1       | value2        | 0
4   | value1       | value2        | 1
```

In the above example the query should return the row with `status` value `0`. If the status with value `0` doesn't exists then it should return any row with `status` value `1`.

Please accept my apologize if my explanation was bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select   SNO, FIRST_COLUMN, SECOND_COLUMN, STATUS
from     mytable
order by STATUS
limit    1
```

Comment: Ooops, it was a simple trick I forgot. Thanks a lot @trincot.

Comment: I have another small doubt, I have 4 rows with `status` value as `1` and I have used `LIMIT 1` then it is returning 4th row instead of 1st row. Can you explain it?

Comment: The SQL engine is free to choose any order if there is no specification in the `order by` on how to sort when `status` is equal. It can be the order of insertion, the order of some index you have specified, ... there can be many explanations. But if it matters to which should be taken, then add other fields to the `order by` clause.

Comment: Thanks once again.